# Is there a way to hide the details in Powershell window when using "New-AzureADMSInvitation" cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am trying to perform an invitation to a bulk list of users to our AzureAD tenant using Powershells "New-AzureADMSInvitation" cmdlet.  I am noticing that a bunch of properties show in the Powershell window for every invite that goes out.  I am wondering if there is a way to hide these details.

My simple invitation script is below if it's needed:

```
foreach ($email in $guests)
       {New-AzureADMSInvitation `
          -InvitedUserEmailAddress $email.InvitedUserEmailAddress `
          -InvitedUserDisplayName $email.Name `
          -InviteRedirectUrl https://teams.microsoft.com `
          -InvitedUserMessageInfo $messageInfo `
          -SendInvitationMessage $true
       }
```

The output shows something like the following:

[image]

If the image doesn't show, the output looks like the following:

```
Id                      : 14baf5ae-4dfb-4012-baee-83a43cb9fc61
InvitedUserDisplayName  : Test User01
InvitedUserEmailAddress : Testuser01@gmail.com
SendInvitationMessage   : True
InviteRedeemUrl         : https://login.microsoftonline.com/redeem?rd=https%3a%2f%2finvitations.microsoft.com%2fredeem%
                          2f%3ftenant%3d165555-2b59-4e40-806d-8a30bdc9cf26%26user%3d14baf5ae-4dfb-4012-baee-83a43cb9f
                          c61%26ticket%3dmfs%25252fQob92cQWtI%25252fX2XgBx5uEGzW8oLYsy9wMxLMeryE%25253d%26ver%3d2.0
InviteRedirectUrl       : https://teams.microsoft.com/
InvitedUser             : class User {
                            Id: a9a6d625-68de-4457-8a35-4ec6cb9fa626
                            OdataType:
                          }

InvitedUserMessageInfo  : class InvitedUserMessageInfo {
                            CcRecipients: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.Recipient]
                            CustomizedMessageBody: Please accept this invitation to collaborate with TestCompany in
                          Microsoft Online for use with TestApp.
                            MessageLanguage:
                          }

InvitedUserType         : Guest
Status                  : PendingAcceptance
```

Is there anyway to hide these details or trim what gets displayed?

Comment: Well, what's your expected output? You can use `Select-Object` to select only the properties you want. Using the `Format-*` cmdlets gives you an option for different formatting options as well while selecting the properties to display.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thank you for the suggestions.  Playing around with the Format-* or Select-Object cmdlets does exactly what I was trying to do.  Not sure why I didn't think of that before.  If you want to post your suggestions as an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: I ended up just storing the details in a variable which hides everything.  I can then report against that variable if needed.  
{ $guestinvites = New-AzureADMSInvitation `
   -InvitedUserEmailAddress $email.InvitedUserEmailAddress `
   -InvitedUserDisplayName $email.Name `
   -InviteRedirectUrl https://teams.microsoft.com `
   -InvitedUserMessageInfo $messageInfo `
   -SendInvitationMessage $true
}